# Help me with my bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, thesis, bibliographystyle, custom-bib

Currently my iob.bbx file in LaTeX looks like this:

```
\ProvidesFile{iob.bbx}[2021/02/24 v1.1z biblatex bibliography style]
%basis
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric-comp}
% New options
\newtoggle{bbx:articletitle}
\newtoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}
\newtoggle{bbx:pageranges}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{articletitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:articletitle}{#1}%
}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{chaptertitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}{#1}%
}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{pageranges}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:pageranges}{#1}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyOption{biblabel}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{plain}
    {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{##1}}
    {%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{brackets}
        {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{##1}}}%
        {%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{dot}
            {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{##1\adddot\midsentence}}
            {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{##1}}}%
        }%
    }%
}
% Alter settings that carry through from biblatex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
  {
    date         = year  ,
    doi          = false , 
    eprint       = false ,
    giveninits   = true  ,
    isbn         = false ,
    maxnames     = 15    ,
    maxcitenames = 2     ,
    pageranges   = true  ,
    url          = false ,
    useprefix    = true
  }

%name bold and family-given
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
% Modify the name format\name bold and family-given
  {
    \DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
        \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}%
        \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcolon\addspace}%
{\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
 \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{family-given-bold}

% Custom field formats 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{date}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  DOI\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:pageranges}{#1}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book, collection, inproceedings]{title}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}

% Simple modifications to punctuation, etc.
\renewcommand*{\begrelateddelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcolon\space}{%
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
% Bibliography strings
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  chapter   = Chapter            ,
  editor    = Ed\adddot          ,
  editors   = Eds\adddot         ,
  in        = In                 ,
  page      = p                  ,
  pages     = pp                 ,
  patentus  = US Patent          ,
  phdthesis = Ph.D.\space Thesis ,
  urlseen   = accessed           ,
  volume    = Vol\adddot
}
% Bibliography macros
\renewbibmacro*{byholder}{%
  \ifnameundef{holder}
    {}
    {%
      \printtext[parens]{\printnames{holder}}%
      \adddot
    }%
}
  
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {}
    {\printtext[date]{\printdate}}%
}
\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{%
  \printfield{eventtitle}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {%
      \printfield{venue}%
      \newunit
      \printeventdate
      \newunit
    }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+booktitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
      \newunit\newblock
    }%
  \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
  \newunit
}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {%
      \clearfield{maintitle}%
       \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
       \clearfield{maintitleaddon}%
    }
    {%
      \iffieldundef{maintitle}
        {}
        {\usebibmacro{maintitle}}%
      \newunit\newblock
    }%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
}
  
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {%
      \printfield{doi}%
      \clearfield{doi}%
    }%
    {%
      \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
        {}
        {\clearfield{doi}}%
    }%
} 

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\newunit}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit
}

\newbibmacro*{related:translatedas}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
      {\printfield{issn}}
      {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \clearfield{volume}%
      \newunit
    }%
}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{eid}%
}
% New bibliography drivers, using the required order of fields. These
% are mainly copied from standard.bbx then modified.
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articletitle}
    {%
      \usebibmacro{title}%
      \printunit{\adddot\addspace}%
    }
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{issn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{booklet}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{collection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit  
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{volume}
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \iftoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}
    {\usebibmacro{title}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{colume}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \iftoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}
    {\usebibmacro{title}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{manual}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \printunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{patent}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{byholder}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{%
       \printlist[][-\value{listtotal}]{location}}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isrn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}
```

my bibstyle looks like this:
**(3) Alsultannty, Y. A.: Al-Shammari, N. N.** Engineering Journal
, 67–80.

but it should look like this:
**[2] Alsultannty, Y. A.; Al-Shammari, N. N.:** Oxygen Specific Power Consumption Compari-son for Air Separation Units, Engineering Journal 18 (2014), Nr. 2, S. 67–80

Also, the program started quoting alphabetically, even though I had written in my main.tex:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,bibstyle=iob, 
citestyle=numeric,
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}\DeclareFieldFormat[book, collection, inproceedings]{title}` is a syntax error. `\DeclareFieldFormat` has two mandatory arguments: The field name and the desired formatting. E.g. `\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{\mkbibamph{#1}}\DeclareFieldFormat[book, collection, inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}`. `\DeclareFieldFormat` should not be used to suppress the output of certain fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the style; one of them is that most of the functions defined appear in conditional constructions (inside if_then_else structures), and it is not clear to me why such constructions are needed.

Parenthesis instead of brackets: The label is defined in a 3 level if_then_else construction

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{biblabel}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{plain}
    {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{##1}}
    {%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{brackets}
        {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{##1}}}%
        {%
          \ifstrequal{#1}{dot}
            {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{##1\adddot\midsentence}}
            {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{##1}}}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

and no option for `biblabel` is called. Thus, the 3 options are false and the final `else` applies.

Similarly for the title of the article.  The toggle `bbx:articletitle` is not set to true. The command sets the value of the toggle to `#1` not to true.

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{articletitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:articletitle}{#1}%
}
```

Thus a change is

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{articletitle}[true]{%
  \settoggle{bbx:articletitle}{true}%
}
```

In addition the option must be invoked (either in  `\ExecuteBibliopgraphyOptions` or in `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`).

For the separators between the names, `\finalnamedelim` set the delimiter before the last name, not after it, and it is generally used to specify ig "and" is used or not.

Finally, the original post has many syntax errors for `\DeclareFieldFormat`. The command takes two mandatory arguments, the field name and the instructions on how to render the field.

The part where the formatting instructions for the fields should look like:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{%
  \bibstring{page}\iftoggle{bbx:pageranges}{#1}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book,collection,inproceedings]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\bibstring{volume}#1}
```

and the following abbreviation/string part

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  chapter   = Chapter            ,
  editor    = Ed\adddot          ,
  editors   = Eds\adddot         ,
  in        = In                 ,
  page      = S\adddot\addnbspace                 ,
  pages     = S\adddot\addnbspace                 ,
  patentus  = US Patent          ,
  phdthesis = Ph.D.\space Thesis ,
  urlseen   = accessed           ,
  volume    = Nr\adddot\addnbspace
}
```

and

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,bibstyle=iob, 
citestyle=numeric,biblabel=brackets,articletitle
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: The suggested change to `\DeclareBibliographyOption{articletitle}` looks odd. Effectively it would make the option set the toggle to true whenever it is used no matter which value is given (so even with `articletitle=false,`). The change is not needed as long as the option is used and set to true (as in the code block shown at the end).

Comment: Not that it matters a lot for the outcome, but the option `\DeclareBibliographyOption{biblabel}` is defined such that if it is not called it does not influence the output at all. So what lives in the final else is irrelevant. Since the option is not called, the definition `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibparens{#1}}` prevails. Of course the solution is to use `biblabel=brackets,` as you point out.